How do I amend my 2018 California Form 540 personal tax return?
I want to amend my 2018 form 540 personal tax return but can only find the online form for year 2023.
To amend, should I include the 3 forms:

2018 540
2018 Schedule CA
latest (2023) Form Schedule X


Use the 2022 edition of the 540 Schedule X form and instructions. There is a space at the top to put the year you are amending. Starting in 2023, 540 Schedule X has been year-specific, but for 2017 through 2022, you are supposed to use the most updated edition of 540 Schedule X (and the most updated edition that allows this is 2022), and put the year you are amending.

user102008:  I asked specifically about amending 2018 form 540, for which I believe I should fill out and mail online 2018 Form 540 (and checkmark AMENDED) and then also fill out and mail Schedule X as you say, marked "2018."  Does that make sense?


I want to amend my 2018 form 540 personal tax return

Why? It's beyond statute of limitations, which is 4 years in California. You can still file it, using the latest version of the form 540 Schedule X (tax year is a fillable field), but to what end? The FTB might (and probably will) reject it.
You can find the 2018 version of the form 540 using the FTB search function.
